# Reached End of File While Parsin

Tags: java, parsing

So I am writting this program for my java class and have everything down except for that the error "reached end of file while parsing", if someone could help give me some insight would be of great help to me!

```
  * COMMENTS: This java program outputs students names and test scores then outputs in order based on their grade.
  */
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

public class lab13
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   { 
      String Last[]= new String[20];
      String First[] = new String[20];
      String inputLine="";;
      int score[]=new int[20];
      int i = 0;
      int total =0;
      String grade = "A";

   //Create a FileReader object to associate the file student.txt
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("student.txt"); //The file student.txt is located in the same folder that has the file lab13. Create a
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); //Load the file student.txt into the buffer (RAM)
   while((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) //Read data from the file
   {
   Last[i] = inputLine;
   First[i] = br.readLine();
   score[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   i++;
   }//end while loop

   //Determine the grade and also display the students' names followed by their test scores and grades.
   for(i =0; i < 20; i++)
   {if( score[i]>= 90)
   grade = "A";
   //YOUR CODING TO DISPLAY GRADE "B", "C", "D", and "F'.
   for(i =0; i < 20; i++)
   {if( score[i]>= 80)
   grade = "B";
   for(i =0; i < 20; i++)
   {if( score[i]>= 70)
   grade = "C";
   for(i =0; i < 20; i++)
   {if( score[i]>= 60)
   grade = "D";
   for(i =0; i < 20; i++)
   {if( score[i]<= 59)
   grade = "F";


   }

   //Determine the highest score
   int highest = score[0];
   for(i = 1; i<20;i++)
   { if (score[i] > highest)
   highest = score[i];
   }
   //Determine the lowest score.
   //YOUR CODING
   int lowest = score[0];
   for(i = 1; i<20;i++)
   { if (score[i] > lowest)
   lowest = score[i];
   }



   //Determine the average
   //YOUR CODING
   int average = score[0];
   for(i = 1; i<20;i++)
   { if (score[i] > average)
   average = score[i];
   }


   //Display the highest score, lowest score and average.

   //YOUR CODING
   System.out.print("Highest Score:"+ highest);
   System.out.print("Lowest Score:"+ lowest);
   System.out.print("Average Score:"+ average);





System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Presumably your file doesn't have an exact multiple of three lines in it. Unfortunately, it's hard to tell as you haven't posted a sample of the file. Also, if that's really how your code looks, I'd *strongly* encourage you to use an IDE which will format the code for you, indenting rather more appropriately. (If the code looks fine in your IDE, then please make sure it looks the same way when posting.)

Comment: As another practical tip for writing good Stack Overflow questions, presumably the exception (which you should give the complete details of) comes early on in the program - making the rest of it irrelevant to the question, really. It's always helpful to provide a [mcve] - where "minimal" is important in helping us to help you without having to look through lots of extraneous code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in:

```
while((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) //Read data from the file
{
    Last[i] = inputLine;
    First[i] = br.readLine();
    score[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    i++;
}
```

You are calling `br.readLine()` three times in the same loop which means that your code will only work if the file you are reading has lines in multiples of three. So this will work:

```
Line 1 //inputLine = br.readLine()) != null
Line 2 //First[i] = br.readLine();
Line 3 //score[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
Line 4 //inputLine = br.readLine()) != null
Line 5 //First[i] = br.readLine();
Line 6 //score[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

The following will fail:

```
Line 1 //inputLine = br.readLine()) != null
Line 2 //First[i] = br.readLine();
Line 3 //score[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
Line 4 //inputLine = br.readLine()) != null
Line 5 //First[i] = br.readLine();
//score[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

When it tries to read the 6th non-existant line with `Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())` you will get that exception.